# place label on top on textfield

Tags: html, css, uitextfield, label

my html:

```
<input type="text" value="" id="email1" class="inputfield_ui" />
<label>Email address 1</label>
```

my inputfield css:

```
width:95%;
z-index:3;
```

my label css:

```
position:absolute;
display:block;
top:8px;
left:11px;
color:#CCCCCC;
z-index:1;
```

when i try to click on the label to enter something it wont allow me to do this... instead will show a default cursor and i will have to click next to the other space of the textfield to write something...

z-indexes are correct , arent they?

**EDIT: SOLUTION**

html:

```
<input type="text" value="" id="email1" class="input" />
<label>Email address 1</label>
<span class="input_bg"></span>
```

css:

```
input{
   background:transparent;
   z-index:1;
}
label{
   z-index:2;
}
.input_bg{
   /*input css with background*/
   z-index:3;
}
```

Comment: Inputs into this field are going to be totally unreadable using your method. http://jsfiddle.net/yLQev/

Comment: i also use javascript to hide/show the label depending on if the input is empty or not...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

html:

```
<input type="text" value="" id="email1" class="input" />
<label>Email address 1</label>
<span class="input_bg"></span>
```

css:

```
input{
   background:transparent;
   z-index:1;
}
label{
   z-index:2;
}
.input_bg{
   /*input css with background*/
   z-index:3;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming this is for the purpose of a textbox watermark?

If this is the case, then I would use CSS to hide the label (don't remove it for accessibility purposes):

```
label
{
  display:none;
}
```

Then use a javascript tool to display the watermarked text. There are a lot of good jQuery solutions for this:

http://code.google.com/p/jquery-watermark/

It's then a case of applying something like:

```
$("#email1").watermark("Email address 1");
```

---

However, this can be improved, so that you don't have to apply this for every single element by doing something like:

```
$(".watermark").watermark($(this).attr("title"));
```

Alternatively, if all your `input`'s have associated `label`s, you can apply them like this:

```
$(".watermark").watermark($("label[for='" + $(this).attr("id") + "']").html());
```

This way if the user doesn't have javascript enabled, theres still the `title` to rely on, and if they don't have CSS, then the label will be shown.

Comment: Why wouldn't you use the text of the associated <label> instead of adding an extra title attribute?

Comment: OP hasn't strictly got an associated `label`, but I've now provided this solution as an option in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

z-index doesn't work without positioning. Try to add `position:relative;` to the input input CSS.

Comment: well now the label disappears... as its behind the input

Comment: Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7BpSh/ You have to explicitly set the label to have a transparent background color.

Comment: That is what z-index does... what you probably want to do is use JavaScript to set a value and then clear it when the user selects the field. HTML5 also has a placeholder attribute which does this, but it doesn't work on older browsers.

Comment: It is possible to make it visible even when it is below the other element by setting the background color of the input to be transparent. The downside is that readability suffers when a value is typed into the text box. Check out @Curt's jquery solution.

Comment: @NathanArthur but what if my input has a background of #f6f6f6 ? EDIT: i think i can add another span element with my bg and z-index:1 , label with z-index:2 and input with z-index:3

Comment: Don't do that. Use JavaScript to set and reset the value attribute.